# MySQL Join needs to show all records from LEFT table

Tags: mysql

I am wondering if someone can help.

Please see below:

> SELECT id,name FROM words;

**id , name**

1   , Still

2   , Sparkling

3   , Fizzy

> SELECT * from translation;

**words_id, lang_id,translation**

1, 1, AStill

1, 2, BStill

2, 1, ASparkling

**I needed result like below:**

**id , name , lang_id, translation**

1,Still, 1, AStill

2, Sparkling, 1, ASparkling

3, Fizzy, NULL , NULL

The query i have tried

> SELECT id,name,lang_id,translation FROM words LEFT JOIN translation ON words_id=id AND lang_id=1;

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f544b/3

Many thanks

Comment: ...and the problem is?

Comment: @Uueerdo This `lang_id=1` and the fact there is no string compare from name to translation

Comment: The query you show above doesn't have the same join condition as in your SQLFiddle. You're missing the term for `lang_id=1`.

Comment: 3. FIZZY do not have lang_id 1 as it is not present in translation table

Comment: bit odd but i have updated Fiddle and seems to be working ! i have spend hours trying to figure it out - so made a very simple table to post here.. i still can't believe it is now working in fiddle, THANKS guys!! Figured it out  I was trying with this incorrect query 

    SELECT id,name,lang_id,translation FROM words LEFT JOIN translation ON words_id=id WHERE lang_id=1;

Answer (score 1):

Your condition `lang_id=1` turns your `LEFT JOIN` into `INNER JOIN`.  The reason is when the condition is not satisfied (ie no entry in `translation` table), it will not display it.  If you want to display everything on the left table, remove the condition `lang_id=1`.

```
SELECT id,name,lang_id,translation 
FROM words 
LEFT JOIN translation ON words_id=id
```

If you need the condition, you can put it in sub-query.

```
SELECT id,name,lang_id,translation 
FROM words w
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * 
    FROM translation
    WHERE lang_id = 1
) t ON t.word_id = w.id
```